# RAILS-4 - has_and_belongs_to_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have two models, sellers and customers.
I want it to be a customer has a seller, many customer can have the same seller.

Ideally i want can do customer.seller = seller
With belongs_to association a seller can belongs to jsute one customer.
I use has_and_belongs_to_many association though a in my cas un customer can only have one seller.

```
 # migration

 create_table :sellers do |t|
   t.string :name 
   t.timestamps null: false
 end

 create_table :customers do |t|
   t.string :name 
   t.timestamps null: false
 end

 create_table :customers_sellers, id: false do |t|
   t.belongs_to :customer, index: true
   t.belongs_to :seller, index: true
 end

 # models/seller.rb
 class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :customers
end

 # models/customer.rb
 class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :sellers
end
```

With that i can't do something like that:

```
customer = Customer.create(name: "John")
seller = Seller.create(name: "Dave")    
customer.sellers = seller
```

I have an error

```
 NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<Seller:0x0000000582fb18>
```

But i can:

```
customer.sellers<< seller
```

But if I change the name of the seller like that

```
Seller.first.name = "Bud"
```

I want it's to be also modified in my customer.sellers.name.

It's possible to make something like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so for a start, `Seller.first.name = "Bud"` does nothing to update the database, that `name` attribute is set on the `Seller.first` instance which is then lost because you've not assigned it to any variable.

So you'll need to change that to either:

```
Seller.first.update name: "Bud"
```

In order to update the DB with the new value, or (more likely) something like:

```
seller = Seller.first
seller.name = "Bud"
seller.save
```

That's step 1, actually getting that value saved into the database.

The second problem is that if you have already read `customer.sellers` from the database then your application already has the value for each of the `name`s stored in memory, you need to reload at least that first record from the DB in order to get the new value:

```
customer.sellers.reload
```

And now (I'm assuming that `Seller.first` is also `customer.sellers.first`) `customer.sellers.first.name` will be `"Bud"`

Comment: Thanks it's work ;) ! But i still can not "customer.sellers = seller", it's not important for my work but i don't understand why.

Comment: `customer.sellers` is a collection, and you're trying to assign a single `seller` to that collection.  [As you can see in the docs](http://devdocs.io/rails/activerecord/associations/classmethods#method-i-has_and_belongs_to_many) you **can** assign to the collection, but you must assign `objects` to it, the plural there is important, you need to assign a collection (an array will work) to the collection.